# How to make an executable binary file, that isnt dependent on .so files

Tags: c++, linux

At the moment I am getting the executable through g++ compiling uisng:

```
g++-4.8 test test.cpp -I /home/pottsie/Documents/Cpp-REST-SDK/casablanca/Release/include/ -lcasablanca -std=gnu++11
```

However when I try that executable on another machine I get the error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcasablanca.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to create an executable that doesnt require me to install casablanca on the computer I want to run it on?

Comment: make a static library instead of a shared one (if you own the source)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `-static` to link statically with the libraries you need. You would need to have those as `.a` then of course.

```
g++-4.8 test test.cpp -I /home/pottsie/Documents/Cpp-REST-SDK/casablanca/Release/include/ -static -lcasablanca -std=gnu++11
```

Comment: as a sidenote: if you just need casablanca to be linked statically you can just drop the -l suffix. -static will try to link everything statically (affecting portability)

Comment: @DavidKernin If you drop the `-l` prefix (which is what I think you mean), you'll have to specify the full path name of the library.  To link only `casablanca` statically, wrap it in `-Wl,-Bstatic -lcasablanca -Wl,-Bdynamic`.  (But you'll probably want all but the basic system libraries linked statically.  In which case, you'll have to wrap all as above, plus use the option `-static-libstdc++`.)

Comment: @Pottsiex5 You can't link something statically if you don't have the static library for it.  From where did you get the library?  You normally should have both a `.a` and a `.so`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I like your solution the most although linking statically all the system libraries will highly impact portability. If that's not at a stake, then it's fine.

Comment: @JamesKanze I got the library from following the build instructions here: https://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20and%20Build%20on%20Linux&version=25 but it only produced .so files. I suppose if i cant get the .a file then I will just have to install it on the other machine.

Comment: @DavidKernin You don't link the _system_ libraries statically, only the others.  (What you consider a system libraries, beyond `libc`, will depend somewhat on your environment, but basically, if you don't want users to have to explicitly install the library, link statically.  And since machines not used for development may not have g++/libstdc++ installed, it's usually preferable to link that statically.)

Comment: @Pottsiex5 It doesn't seem to be using `configure`, so I don't know.  (`configure` usually has an option to build the static library.)  You might look at the `cmake` file to see if there is a separate target.  (Alternatively, if you're familiar with the tool chain, it shouldn't be too difficult to create one.  I don't know `cmake`, however, so I can't help too much there.)